# Kotlin How to put data

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, layout

I have a single layout in which i have text view and image view and in other activity i h a list view in that list view i have 100 items so on every item click i want to open that single layout but only every click want to chnage text view and image views

Please someone solve this

Comment: Can you show us your code so that we can help?

Answer (score 0):

Base on your information:

- You have 2 layout which mean activity

**First Activity**

You have like 100 items.

**Second Activity**

You have Textview / Imageview .... somthing like that.

> **what you try to do is open detail of what you click right**

Here How it work:

When your item is clicked , you have to call that function and pass the params (First Activity)

```
 fun gotoDetail(title: String?, imageUrl: String) {
    Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("title", title)
        putExtra("url", imageUrl)
        startActivity(this)
    }
}
```

How to get values (Second Activity):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
    ........
    var title = intent.getStringExtra("title" )
    var url = intent.getStringExtra("url")
    .............
}
```

It's good to goo.